# Incorrect URL after changing routing in Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am having trouble with rendering URL addresses after changing routing.

**Routing Configuration**

```
public class AccountArea : AreaRegistration
{
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Account",
            "Account/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:  new[] {
                "Application.Controllers.Account"
            }
        );
    }

    public override string AreaName => "AccountArea";
}

public class FrontArea : AreaRegistration
{
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Front",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:  new[] {
                "Application.Controllers.Front"
            }
        );
    }

    public override string AreaName => "FrontArea";
}
```

and `RouteConfig`:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    }
```

**Controllers**

```
// on folder Controllers/Front/
namespace Application.Controllers.Front
class HomeController : Controller
{
   ActionResult Index(){ ... }
}

// on folder Controllers/Account/
Application.Controllers.Account
class UserController : Controller
{
   ActionResult Index(){...}
}
```

I have changed routing because I want to separate the controllers into 2 subfolders, Front and Account.

This configuration allows me to divide the application into 2 parts, differentiated by using URL address.

```
localhost/Home/Index [namespace: Application.Controllers.Front]
localhost/Account/User/Index- [namespace: Application.Controllers.Account]
```

after entering the address to the browser

```
localhost/Home/Index - will start method Index from HomeController
localhost/Account/User/Index - will start method Index from UserController
```

A problem appears when on URL address `localhost/Home/Index` and I try rendering URL address belonging to `localhost/Account/User/Index`.

When I use `@Url.Action("Index","User")` address will be rendered, but without the "Account" prefix in the URL.

> I receive: `/User/Index`
>
> But, I expect: `/Account/User/Index`

And vice versa, on `localhost/Account/User/Index` I can't render correct URL address belonging to `localhost/Home/Index`.

This problem I can solve using `Url.RouteUrl` like

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Account", new {controller = "User", account = "Index"} )
```

but, this requires route name, which I don't want to provide.

Answer (score 0):

When using Area routes, all of the `UrlHelper` URL resolution methods (such as `ActionLink` or `Url.Action`) will use the *same area* by default.

**Linking from Front Area to Front Area**

```
@Url.Action("Index", "User")
```

To specify to go to a *different* area, you must **explicitly** specify the area in the route values that are passed in to `Url.Action`.

**Linking from Front Area to Account Area**

```
@Url.Action("Index", "User", new { area = "Account" })
```

The same goes for links generated inside of the `Account` area. You will need to explicitly override the current area name with `Front`.

**Linking from Account Area to Front Area**

```
@Url.Action("Index", "User", new { area = "Front" })
```

> this requires route name, which I don't want to provide.

#### Option 1 - Use Constants for Areas

Make a set of constants that you use for all of your area strings in the application.

```
public static class Areas
{
    public const string Front = "Front";
    public const string Account = "Account";
}
```

And use like

```
@Url.Action("Index", "User", new { area = Areas.Front })
```

#### Option 2 - Use T4MVC

There is a package called [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation) that generates constants for your project so you can replace routing and URL generation without using magic strings.

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Areas.Front.User.Index)
```

#### Option 3 - Use Extension Methods

Another option would be to build your own extension methods to replace `Url.Action`, `Html.ActionLink`, `RedirectToAction`, etc.

```
@Url.ActionToFront("Index", "User")
```

This is a lot of action methods to create, though.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i wrote that i dont want to fill Area or Route name :), this works for namespaces, this example can dedect namespace, and if i use URL address localhost/User/Index i recive 404, but if i use localhost/Account/User/Index this match namespace witch route and work correctly :)

Comment: i'am thinking about ovveride or make extensions of UrlHelper, by find Controler namespace using typeof().Namespace, matching this namespace with routing and return Url.RouteUrl( "recived_route", ....) this this extensions should be implemented on every Html method like as Partial, RenderAction, ....

Comment: Using an extension method might work, but it is usually far more common to link to other places *within* the same area than it is to link to other areas so this isn't as big of a deal as you might think. You can make extension methods, but you are basically just moving the problem to another place. `RouteUrl` also doesn't solve much - it works the same as `Url.Action` if you don't specify the area name as a route value - the only difference is you can optionally specify the route name to narrow down the match to a single route.

Comment: i dont like to hardcode string in code :) this option may be ok, if compiler will check this at building project :)

Comment: Then I suggest making a static class called `Areas` and make constants for your area names. You can then construct URLs like `@Url.Action("Index", "User", new { area = Areas.Front })`. Alternatively, use [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation), which allows you to configure MVC without using magic strings.